# WPF DataGrid Highlighting all cells in a column that match the selected cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I fill an `ObservableCollection<>` (also tried a `List<>`) with a custom Class. I've bound the collection to the DataGrid and defined the columns. Now I want to select a cell and have the other cells (in the same column although data in other columns won't ever match) that have the same string in it to be highlighted.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CellHighlighterConverter x:Key="cellHighlighterConverter" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ScanCollectionViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView" />
    <Style x:Key="CenterCell" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CellPad" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,15,0" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CellHighlighterStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsMatching, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource cellHighlighterConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <DataGrid x:Name="scans" DataContext="{StaticResource ScanCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Margin="10" MouseUp="scans_MouseUp" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Device Name" Binding="{Binding Hostname}" Width="125" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Scan Date" Binding="{Binding ScanDate}" Width="75" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterCell}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="GUID" Binding="{Binding GUID}" Width="300" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterCell}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MAC" Binding="{Binding MAC}" Width="105" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellHighlighterStyle}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
private ObservableCollection<Scan> ReadFiles()
    {
        scanList = new List<Scan>();
        ...
        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            Scan newScan = new Scan();
            ...fill newScan with data
            scanList.Add(newScan);
        }
        scanList = scanList.OrderBy(x => x.Hostname).ThenByDescending(x => x.ScanDate).ToList();
        scanCollection = new ObservableCollection<Scan>(scanList);
        return scanCollection;        
   }
```

Ways I've tried to accomplish this. Added a property to the class, then on mouse up, set that property if data matches (this works), then use a converter to set the background based on that data. Either the grid isn't refreshing or something else is wrong. Am I on the right track or is there a better way?

```
private void scans_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string selMAC = ((Scan)((DataGrid)sender).SelectedValue).MAC;
        foreach (Scan scan in scanList)//((DataGrid)sender).Items.OfType<Scan>().ToList() )
        {
            // compare values
            if (scan.MAC == selMAC)
            {
                scan.IsMatch = true;
            } else
            {
                scan.IsMatch = false;
            }
            //scans.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
}

public class CellHighlighterConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if( (Boolean)value )
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        return SystemColors.AppWorkspaceColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class Scan
{
    public Scan()
    {
        this.IsMatch = false;
    }

    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string ScanDate { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string MAC { get; set; }
    public bool IsMatch { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scan` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise notificattion for `IsMatch` property:

```
private bool _IsMatch;
public bool IsMatch 
{
    get { return _IsMatch; }
    set 
    { 
         if (_IsMatch == value) return;
         _IsMatch = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("IsMatch");
    }
}
```

without such notification Convert method isn't triggered even if you change IsMatch.

other things I would fix:

`Convert` method should return Brush, not Color

```
{
    return (bool)value ? Brushes.Green : SystemColors.AppWorkspaceBrush;
}
```

use `SelectionChanged` event instead of `MouseUp`. MouseUp can happen on the same cell multiple times, no need to search mathes each time

Comment: I think I've implemented it correctly and if I put a Breakpoint in my MouseUp event (I know, I haven't changed it yet) I can see that IsMatch is updated to True but the DataGrid is not changed. Am I missing something in my XAML?

Comment: @awsnap, `Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsMatching` shouldn't is be ` IsMatch` property there?

Comment: Boom. smh. Thanks, this is perfect and gave my enough info to teach myself the full implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged and not just copy/paste.